# Сніговий чи сніжний покрив

Tags: вибір-слова, прикметники

СУМ-11

> [Сніговий](http://sum.in.ua/s/snighovyj) 1. Прикм. до сніг. /  Зробл. із снігу або в снігу. 2.
>   Вкритий снігом.
>
> [Сніжний](http://sum.in.ua/s/snizhnyj) 1. Прикм. до сніг. //  Зробл. із снігу або в снігу. 2.
>   Вкритий снігом.

В [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9) ці слова подаються, як синоніми.

[Літературне слововживання](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53409/32217.html)

> *Сніговий.* 1. Прикм. (переважно як відносний) від сніг; який утворився
>   зі снігу, зроблений зі снігу; який несе сніг; вкритий снігами; схожий
>   на сніг тощо. Вж. зі сл.: межа, гора, гірка, вода, намет, стіна, баба,
>   зима, пороша, буря, буран, колір, людина, плуг. 2. Як складова частина
>   ботанічних і зоологічних назв. Вж. зі сл.: кальвіль, подорожник,
>   плісень, барс, чайка.
>
> *Сніжний.* Прикм. (переважно як якісний) від сніг; який несе сніг,
>   укритий снігами, схожий на сніг тощо. Вж. зі сл.: зима, вітер, курява,
>   рівнина, поле, полотно.

Така ж є інформація на сайті [Мова -ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/snigovuj-i-snizhnuj)

Який прикметник потрібно використати до іменника ["покрив"](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokryv) (1. Верхній шар, який покриває що-небудь.(СУМ-11)

Стаття в [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2)  остаточно мене запутала, назва "сніговий покрив", а визнаження "сніжний покрив".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зверніть увагу - у тому ж Словнику синонімів коло слова сніжний пише "рідше". Бо й справді, якщо навіть в Інтернеті шукати "сніжний покрив", то пошукові системи перш за все видають сторінки із де йдеться про "сніговий покрив". Хоч, ми можемо зустріти словосполучення "сніжний покрив", наприклад, в [книжці з географії](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=3otFEvDlLCIC&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%22&source=bl&ots=RhZEdM-LiB&sig=5Cbx7aPq7psFKTCTGnDpNO0STto&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJgPLbuN7fAhVIFiwKHW7lCRUQ6AEwC3oECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%22&f=false). Також зустрічаємо його в різних статтях на Вікіпедії - про [кріосферу](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) (в розділі "кріогенні утворення"), про [лавину](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) тощо.

А ось [документ](https://ldubgd.edu.ua/sites/default/files/3_nauka/konkurs/bezpeka_karpat_.pdf), який називається "МОНІТОРИНГ **СНІГОВОГО ПОКРИВУ** В РАЙОНІ ЧОРНОГІРСЬКОГО ХРЕБТА СХІДНИХ КАРПАТ ЯК КРИТЕРІЙ ТЕХНОГЕННОЇ БЕЗПЕКИ РЕГІОНУ". Тобто бачимо, що вживаються як одне так і інше словосполучення.

Але, мені ще також вдалося знайти інформацію, яка розділяє ці два слова. Г. X. ЩЕРБАТЮК в статті "[СНІЖНИЙ І СНІГОВИЙ](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine6-14.pdf)" пише:

> ...за прикметником **сніжний** закріплюється значення «**багатий на сніг,
>   подібний до снігу** (як сніг)», а **сніговий** набуває значення «**зроблений
>   із снігу**».

І на сайті [Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53409/32217.html) (Літературне вживання):

> **Сніговий**. 1. Прикм. (**переважно як відносний**) від сніг; який
>   утворився зі снігу, зроблений зі снігу; який несе сніг; вкритий
>   снігами; схожий на сніг тощо. Вж. зі сл.: межа, гора, гірка, вода,
>   намет, стіна, баба, зима, пороша, буря, буран, колір, людина, плуг. 2.
>   Як складова частина ботанічних і зоологічних назв. Вж. зі сл.:
>   кальвіль, подорожник, плісень, барс, чайка.
>
> **Сніжний**. Прикм. (**переважно як якісний**) від сніг; який несе сніг, укритий снігами, схожий на сніг тощо. Вж. зі сл.: зима, вітер, курява,
>   рівнина, поле, полотно.

Гадаю, що покрив все ж зроблений зі снігу, а тому правильніше буде сказати "сніговий покрив".

Comment: @MariiaMatskevych, там, де я цитую інформацію із Словопедії я хотів виділити саме те, що сніговий він переважно вживається як відносний, а сніжний як якісний (як на мене це також має значення при розгляді цього питання). А от те, що ви посилалися на МОВА ДНК Націїї я, чесно кажучи, не помітив, тому якщо вважаєте за потрібне, я можу забрати цю частину із відповідді.

Comment: Виправив, дякую, що помітили і повідомили мене.

Answer (score 2):

**Сніговий покрив** -це науковий термін і його вживання знаходимо у [Словнику термінів](https://pidcom/75706/ekologiya/slovnik_terminiv_ekologichna_otsinkaruchniki), в [енциклопедії](http://leksika.com.ua/18310506/ure/snigoviy_pokriv), у статті ["ХАРАКТЕРИСТИКА СНІГОВОГО ПОКРОВУ СУМСЬКОЇ ОБЛАСТІ
ЗА РЕЗУЛЬТАТАМИ СПОСТЕРЕЖЕНЬ 2005-2017 РОКІВ" А.О. Корнус, І.O. Лисенко](http://scinotesgeo.at.ua/Volume_8/Kornus_Lysenko.pdf).

**Сніжний покрив** ми ж не знаходимо у словниках або в іншій науковій літературі.